# Hibernate JPA query hint javax.persistence.cache.storeMode not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching

I have a Criteria query in JPA and I want to cache the result.

```
CriteriaQuery<AnEntity> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(AnEntity.class);
TypedQuery<AnEntity> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

Setting a hint using hibernate works great, the query gets cached and retrieved from cache.

```
typedQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
```

However when I try to use the JPA hint nothing happens.

```
typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.REFRESH);
```

Hibernate version 4.3.11 (managed using spring data jpa)

Comment: Which version of Hibernate?

Comment: It is hibernate 4.3.11